# Is there a tensor.item() equivalent for a tensor containing a list in pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

In pytorch, if I define a one-element tensor as follows:

```
>>> import torch
>>> target1 = torch.tensor([5])
```

I'm able to pull out the value of its one element like this:

```
>>> target1.item()
5
```

What I would like to know is if when my tensor is defined as:

```
target2 = torch.tensor([[5], [5], [5], [5]])
```

Is there some way (similar or not to *.item()* above) to pull out all of its entries into a list like:

```
>>> target2.(something)
[5, 5, 5, 5]
```

I can't seem to find any function in the documentation that supports an operation like this.

Comment: Kindly do not tag such questions as `artificial-intelligence` (removed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

`target2.numpy().ravel()` or

`target2.view(-1).numpy()` or

`target2.view(target2.numel()).numpy()`

```
Out[1]: array([5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @EduardoBarrera well, based on your question, it still misses the `.tolist()` call, so not _exactly_, but correct anyway.